# Tighten vote-to-close conditions for high-score questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I've seen some questions with score 5+ on the verge of getting closed and sometimes I thought "Mmmh that's a shame".

I know I can vote to re-open but perhaps we don't have to go through that. Surely a high score is indicative of a "question of interest" and should perhaps be taken into account in the vote-to-close system.

Allow me to nuance that though: closing a high-score question as a duplicate is perfectly fine to me (and is the right thing to do) but apart from that, is it ok for me to close a question I think is off-topic and ignore everybody who think otherwise?

Couple of suggestions:

- Increase VTC threshold
- Has to be VTCed by a relevant bronze tag badge holder

Something similar to [Reduce the close-vote threshold when the question is heavily downvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234231/414537) but the other way round ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is it ok for me to close a question I think is off-topic and ignore everybody who think otherwise?

Yes, it is. I've seen many cases where a question's score is inflated through Hot Network Question upvotes. If it's off-topic, it's off-topic; the score doesn't matter.

> Surely a high score is indicative of a "question of interest" and should perhaps be taken into account in the vote-to-close system.

It is already, by psychology; users are less likely to vote to close an upvoted question than a downvoted one<sup>[citation needed]</sup>. An alternative if you don't want to vote to close: consider improving the question so that it becomes on-topic for the site.